# If URL x, load template, else single.php (on Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom posts that I want to be shown in a different template.

Right now I have custom posts on:

```
www.mywebsite.com/travel/post-name
```

All other (default) posts are on:

```
www.mywebsite.com/post-name
```

Basically, I'm trying to find a `function.php` code, that identifies URL and applies another template.

So, if path `www.mywebsite.com/travel/post`, then load post in `traveltemplate.php`

else, `single.php`

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. this is not categories, so `in_category` `category ID` and `category` won't work.

I'm looking for a rough url identifier.

Comment: All you have to do is name your template file properly to begin with, then WP will do the rest automatically. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/

Comment: brilliant, exactly what I wanted. Worked like a charm. Please post as an answer so I could accept and upvote for others.

Comment: I would argue that the question should be closed for not have done enough research instead. What you're asking about is very well documented in their manual (which is the link that helped you). No need to duplicate the documentation here on SO.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has a pretty sophisticated system to pick the “correct” template for specific pieces of content already, based on certain file naming patterns.

Check https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/, it explains how that looks for custom post types.

> - single posts of a custom post type will use `single-{post_type}.php`
> - and their archives will use `archive-{post_type}.php`